# getLastKnownLocation returning null even though GPS is enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, gps

So during my testing of my app, I was turning off and on my GPS trying to figure out the best way of checking to see if the GPS was enabled. Unfortunately, I was unable to find the best way. However, the code was working when the GPS was enabled but not it isn't working now. It is saying location.getLatitude() is a null object reference.

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    View myView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MapFragment mapFrag;





    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_layout, container, false);
        return myView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapFrag = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        //mapFrag.onResume();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            double lat =  location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 13);
            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

        } else {
            final AlertDialog alertDialogGPS = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

            alertDialogGPS.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialogGPS.setMessage("Looks like you have not given GPS permissions. Please give GPS permissions and return back to the app.");
            alertDialogGPS.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialogGPS.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intentSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intentSettings);
                    alertDialogGPS.dismiss();
                }

            });

            alertDialogGPS.show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why it is returning a null when it worked before, any ideas how to handle this in a fragment?

UPDATE:

I even tried this, and still get it:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            if(locationManager != null) {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 13);
                mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            } else
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, (LocationListener) this);
            }

        }
```

Error Message I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi, PID: 18112
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.ThirdFragment.onMapReady(ThirdFragment.java:84)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                      at xz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                      at maps.ad.u$5.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 163 Google release certificates
D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 318 Google certificates
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18112 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the new and the old location API's together when you shouldnt.

to get the last known location all your have to do is call

```
mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

once the location service was connected.

read how to use the new location API

[Last location api](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation)

Comment: Where exactly am I putting `mLocationClient.getLastLocation();` or what am I replacing with that?

Comment: These are used with Fusion api because previous ones are deprecated. Use like LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)

Comment: please follow below link Fusion Api to get latest api for location.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html